# Node: Import Typescript library with npm/yarn

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, npm, yarnpkg

I have a Node-Typescript project. That project has a dependency on another Typescript project. The dependency points directly to my Bitbucket repository. When I run "yarn install" the whole repository is cloned into my node_modules. That's perfect. In the root directory of my library-project is a index.ts file which contains the line "export * from './source'" to make it all available. I import and use some classes from the library in my code.

When I compile the project I get the exception: "Cannot find module './source'.". Furthermore it is not possible to automatically import the classes in Intellij.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Note:
I know, that the "right" way for libraries would be to generate JS and typing files and put the compiled source in to a private NPM repository. Since I am the only one that uses that library, I would like to have a simpler approach and just import the uncompiled Typescript into my project.

Comment: You may not be compiling the node module you are importing from your npm repo. When you compile your main project the node_modules are generally ignored by tsc. When you run you compiled js it is expecting js in the node_modules and cant find it.